# potential energy of two atom Molecule in case of ionic bond

Tags: solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

The formula for the potential energy of a two atomic Molecule in case of a ionic bond is given by:
$$E_p(r)= -\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r} + \frac{b}{r^9}$$

What is the physical meaning of these terms?

What I understand is that the first term is the Coulomb attraction term (between one electron cloud and the nucleus of the other) and the second term is a repulsion energy between electron clouds. Am I right? Why is there a $9$ in the repulsion energy term?

Thanks!

Comment: Because it makes the repulsion really big really fast as the ions get too near each other. There is not a physical basis for it, per se.